# Django listview capture value from url then pass to template

Tags: django

I captures value from url using

```
def get_queryset(self):
    name= self.request.GET.get('name')
```

Now want to pass this varible to template. Just like:
your have searched: {{ name }}

Comment: I don't see why you do that in `get_queryset`. That's for, well, getting a queryset. You should do this in `get_context_data` and add it to the context dict there.

Comment: This is *not* what should be implemented in the `get_queryset` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a class-based view, the `get_queryset` is used to - like the name suggests - construct a queryset of objects, for example in a `ListView` this queryset is than passed to the template such that one can *render* the items in the queryset.

Here you want to *add* something to the context dictionary, in that case you need to patch the [**`get_context_data`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data) function, so:

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    context['name'] = self.request.GET.get('name')
    return context
```

Note that you should return a dictionary, so here we *alter* the dictionary that we obtain from a super call. Calling the `super().get_context_data(..)` method is *not* required, you could for example return a dictionary with only the attributes you want. But it is typically not good design, since a view typically already adds a lot of data to the context dictionary, and now you can no longer use that in the template.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    name = self.request.GET.get('name')
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context["name"] = name
    return context
```

now the name variable is available in template

in template you can use {{name}}